# Easy LWC question about setting values when fields return blank in the component

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

**Problem.** I have a related record to an opportunity and I'm able to get the data from that record to populate successfully on the LWC. I would like to add some checks incase the fields I'm bringing in from that record (Name, Contact, etc.) are blank (e.g. Related record doesn't have a field value display 'NO CONTACT').

I've looked through the LWC Recipes for examples of getters and setters, but all their examples seem to be related to a user setting a value from the UI rather than checking a value returned by a related record. I've pasted a code sample below. **BONUS POINTS: Any recommended resources for getters and setters on LWC would be greatly appreciated.**

**HTML for LWC**

```
    <template>
    <lightning-card title='Payment'>
        <template if:true={record.data}>
        <div class='slds-card'>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <span class="slds-form-element__label">Contact</span>
                    <p>{paymentContact}</p>
        </div>
        </template>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**JS for LWC**

```
export default class OppPaymentMethod extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId;
    @track record;
    @track error;
    @track nameTest = 'THIS IS A TEST';


    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    record; 

    get paymentContact() {
        return getFieldValue(this.record.data, PAYMENT_CONTACT_NAME_FIELD);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways for this.

**HTML Way:**

I will explain with your wired property `record.data`. Let's say there's a field `Contact_Name__c`. You can add checks like below.

```
<template if:true={record.data.Contact_Name__c}>{record.data.Contact_Name__c}</template>
<template if:false={record.data.Contact_Name__c}>No Contact</template>
```

You need to add checks in the parent that section if `record.data` has value or not.

---

**JavaScript Way**

Add checks in the getter method and return the result as per conditions.

```
get paymentContact() {
    let val = getFieldValue(this.record.data, PAYMENT_CONTACT_NAME_FIELD);
    if(val){
        return val;
    }
    return 'No Contact';
}
```

You can use this directly in the HTML file like `{paymentContact}`.

Remember setters you need only with public properties. Getters you can use with both public and private.

[Getters/Setters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_props_public)

Comment: What if i have multiple fields? Are you suggesting use the Template conditional every field I want to check?

Comment: IT WORKED! Thank you. I was lost on the getter and setter, and assumed I had to use a setter to get the result. Didn't realize I could add logic to the getter.

Comment: If you have multiple fields then you need to use the javascript approach, Its a very lengthy question to answer here. But in short, what I would do is, I will fill out the values with a message using js and I would render that directly on the HTML in a classical fashion like `obj.Field__c`.

Comment: Do you have a resource on that? I'm not familiar with the classical fashion....

Comment: I mean if the value is not present in a field I will write the message directly in that field and render that field directly like `{object.field}`. That way it will get a value at any condition. I will update the answer with this example as well, in some time

Comment: Thanks Rahul. Adding that example to the above would be most appreciated.